# How sorting list of string by length

Tags: prolog

Hi i having a problem with sort list like:

```
sort([p v q v r, p, p v q], R).
```

expected result is

```
R = [p, p v q, p v q v r]
```

Is any built in sort in swi-prolog which allow me that or i have to write it myself.

Comment: Best is to use keysort/2 with key the textual representation.

Comment: sort/2 already does it... what's wrong with it ?

Comment: @CapelliC yeah its work my bad. Can i have another question to you?

Comment: @lurker even when i have :- op(500, xfy, v). ?

Comment: That's fine. But you didn't say that in your problem statement. :)

Comment: @Capellic: sort/2 will take into account `(v)/2` first. But the left operator should come first.